# selecting sequence from string in DNA stringset

Tags: r, string

I'm analyzing a large DNA stringSet like this:

```
SEQUENCE

A DNAStringSet instance of length 6
     width seq                                                                                                          names               
[1]    253 GAACAGCATGAATGTTAAAACTGAAATGGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATG...GTATTATGGCATCATGATGAATGATGGTTAGGTTTTCAGAAAAAGCAGAAGA C3
[2]    158 TATATATATATAGTCAATTCGAGGATGTTAGATCGACAATGGGGATTATAGAA...AGCAAGAATTAGCAGGACCACTCCGGATACTATTCCAGAGTTTCCTTGCAAA B4
[3]    619 ATAGACATACACACAAATATTTTTATATCACATGCATACCCATACACACACAT...TCATATATAGACACAAATATATATATACATATTTATACATATATATATATAT A0
[4]    359 TCACCAGTGGCAGCCGCGGCTACAGCAAAAGGTGGCCGGCCAAGGAGTGTCGT...GGTGTCGCGTGCCCTTGTGGACACGGGCTGTACAACGACCCTGATGACTCCG A1
[5]    239 GAAGTGGTAAAGAGTGCGATGCGCTGAAAAAAGAGAGAACAGTACTTGAAATG...CCACACTTCAAGTACTGTTCTCTCTTTTTTCAGCGCATCGCACTCTTTACCA A2
[6]    212 CAAAAAGAAGGTTATGGTGACTGTTTGGTGGTGTACTGCTGGACCCATCCCCT...ATAGGGCCAATCATTCTTCATGACAATGCTCGACCACACGTTTTACTAATGA A3
... .... .....
```

well, supposing I need to find a specific sequence, for example `GCGGCTACAGCAAAAGGTGGCCGGCCAAGG` in the string with the name A1, I don't understand how to obtain it. I've tried this:

```
s1= SEQUENCE[4]
  A DNAStringSet instance of length 1
    width seq                                                                                                           names               
[1]   359 TCACCAGTGGCAGCCGCGGCTACAGCAAAAGGTGGCCGGCCAAGGAGTGTCGT...AGGTGTCGCGTGCCCTTGTGGACACGGGCTGTACAACGACCCTGATGACTCCG A1
```

Now it is a simple example where I can see that the name `A1` corresponds to the string `[4]`, but if only know the name in more than 10000 strings, I cannot do this.  Anyway, I only want to obtain the sequences, not the name, not the width, but I don't know how to extract it from this stringset. 
Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One base R option is to use `grepl`.  As a smaller version of your original data, I am using this:

```
sequences <- c("GAACAGCATG", "TATATATATA", "ATAGACATAC")
sequences[grepl("GAACA", sequences)]

[1] "GAACAGCATG"
```

If you are using a data frame to store your sequence information, then use something like this:

```
df[,grepl(df$seq, "GCGGCTACAGCAAAAGGTGGCCGGCCAAGG")]
```